# book about smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Could you let me know about books that explains the ideas of smart pointer very clearly (beginner, intermediate and advanced level)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

A little more advanced, the book [Modern C++ Design](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201704315) has a lot of worthy content. Luckily enough for you the chapter about Smart Pointers is [available online](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25264). Take note however, that this is about the functioning and design, not only about usage, so should be treated as advanced level.

Answer (score 5):

A good starting place might be this Wikipedia article, [*Smart Pointers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Answer (score 4):

Scott Meyers has an a few items on it. You might not need a whole book.

Scott Meyers books :

[Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)

[More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)

[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)

Comment: Could you let me know the name of the book please?

Comment: buy all of scott's books, they complement each other -- and kick ass. Their are three : effective C++ , more effective C++, and effective STL.

Answer (score 1):

[This one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beyond-Standard-Library-Introduction-Boost/dp/0321133544) illustrates the old smart pointers (from the stl)  and the new ones from boost -- in adequate detail.

p.s., if your new to C++ you might want to skip this book as it's not worth buying it for just one article.

Comment: I have always wondered what they are, you sure they are monkeys ?

Comment: The cover? They're some species of lemur (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemur). Not sure which one, though.

Comment: Yeah, what is it with animals on programming book covers? "Oh, look at the wittle cutsie puppy! I'll buy 10!"

Comment: OK. Ill split the difference to a the common ordo: Primate.